# Support for Add function in .NET Toolkit for Rally API

Tags: rally

I am currently running with version 1.43 of the Rally WebServices API. I have been adding test cases to test sets by updating the test set after adding the test case to the testcases array within the test set.
This has been working well for several months, but I have just started to get the error:
"Could not set value for Test Cases: null"
The first test case I add to a new test set does not get the error. It is only when I have two or more test cases in the test case array that the error is returned.
I contacted Rally support and they recommended switching to v2.0 and using the following:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testset/14469862335/testcases/add?key=nnn

Request Body:

{
    "CollectionItems": [
    {"_ref": "/testcase/14469885324"},
    {"_ref": "/testcase/14469885842"},
    {"_ref": "/testcase/14469886070"},
    {"_ref": "/testcase/14469887154"}
]
}
```

The .NET toolkit does not support Add as far as I know, and I don't think there is a way of using "CollectionItems" either.
I am wondering if functionality to do this is planned for the .NET toolkit? If not, is there another way I can achieve this with the toolkit?

Thanks for your help,
Caspar Davey.

Comment: Rally support have just confirmed that this is a defect. Once test cases have been written to a test set, subsequent updates to the test case array fail with the error : "Could not set value for Test Cases: null". This also occurs with v2.0 as well.

Comment: Yea, I reported this issue to rally yesterday and they confirmed that its a bug. I am running a java application (using Rally java tool kit) with wsapi version 1.37.